# Pybind11 - Capture output in realtime from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++, real-time, pybind11

Using Pybind11, I am able to call a C++ native function from my Python code.
My C++ programme has a long-running function that keeps on going until explicitly stopped and this function generates some output using std::cout. As this long-running function never returns due to its nature, I am trying to get the output of this C++ code in my Python code for further processing.

I am aware of this: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/utilities.html#capturing-standard-output-from-ostream however I really do not see how to reflect the C++ generated output into my Python code.

Here is the code:

```
int myFunc()
{
    ...
    for(;;) { // Can be only stopped if requested by user
        std::cout << capturedEvent;
    }
    ...

    return 0;
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(Handler, m) {

    // Add a scoped redirect for your noisy code
    m.def("myFunc", []() {
        py::scoped_ostream_redirect stream(
            std::cout,                               // std::ostream&
            py::module_::import("sys").attr("stdout") // Python output
        );
        myFunc();
});

...
}
```

And Python:

```
from Handler import myFunc
from random import random

DATA = [(random() - 0.5) * 3 for _ in range(999999)]

def test(fn, name):
    result = fn()
    print('capturedEvent is {} {} \n\n'.format(result, name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test(myFunc, '(PyBind11 C++ extension)')
```

I would like to retrieve, in realtime, the content of the C++ `capturedEvent` variable.
If there is another approach than capturing stdout, (maybe sharing a variable in realtime?) please, let me know, maybe my strategy is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you have the C++ program write to a pipe or a pain file instead of cout?

Comment: @Botje I thought of writing to a log file however I was worried about performance (even this app will never process thousands of operations per second), haven't thought of a pipe, what would be the approach to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give or take you solution seems ok.
One think that you assume wrong is that the result will get the output of the stdout.
That is wrong. The output of c++ stdout will go to the pythons sys.stdout, and will in theory (thats what happens to me) be printed on your terminal.